# Flux of a unit sphere cap

Tags: calculus, surface-integrals

so I am stuck with this problem, english is not my first language but I believe it is called flux, feel free to rename the question otherwise;

calculate the flow of the field
$F = \langle x, y, z \rangle$ outwards through the unit sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ above $z=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt2}$

[http://prntscr.com/b9rs7k] (from mathematica)..

so some people say that you can use the divergence theorem for similar problems to make it real easy, some however say that in some cases it wont work and I cannot tell if this is one of those cases since I am too wet behind the ears =).

I am unsure of what to do with the z limit here, which I guess translates to what limits to use for $\phi$. I try to think of $\phi$ as the angle available on the z plane it makes no sense to me at the moment..  is it simply $0\le\phi\le\pi$

is this even remotely right? (problem being I cant control the answer)

$\begin{eqnarray}
r_\theta\times r_\phi&=&\left|\begin{matrix}i& j& k\\ 
-\sin\theta\sin\phi&\cos\theta\sin\phi& 0\\ \cos\theta\cos\phi& \sin\theta\cos\phi& -\sin\phi
\end{matrix}\right|
\\ \ \\ 
&=&(-\cos\theta\sin^2\phi, -\sin\theta\sin^2\phi, -\sin\phi\cos\phi).
\end{eqnarray}$

Turning it away from centre (right? once again I dont understand fully)

$\begin{eqnarray}
F(r(\theta,\phi))\cdot(r_\theta\times r_\phi)&=& 
(\cos\theta\sin\phi\cos\phi,\sin\theta\sin\phi\cos\phi,\cos^2\phi) \\
& &\cdot(\cos\theta\sin^2\phi, \sin\theta\sin^2\phi, \sin\phi\cos\phi)
\\ &=&
\cos^2\theta\sin^3\phi\cos\phi+\sin^2\theta\sin^3\phi\cos\phi+\sin\phi\cos^3\phi\\
&=&
\sin\phi\cos\phi(\cos^2\theta\sin^2\phi+\sin^2\theta\sin^2\phi+\cos^2\phi)\\
&=&\sin\phi\cos\phi.
\end{eqnarray}$

$\int\!\!\!\!\int_S F\cdot n\, dS = \int_0^{2\pi}\!\!\int_0^{\pi}\sin\phi\cos\phi\,d\theta d\phi$
This rurns out to be 0  ...   hmm cant be right?

...
or should/could I go with a triple integral
(cant seem to get the root fraction limit to fit properly *mathjax issue)
$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\int_{0}^{1}[function] \,dr\,d\theta\,d\phi$

or is it $\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\int_{\dfrac{1}{\sqrt2}}^{1}$..  hmm where does the z limit come into play?

Ok, so as I guess you can see I am confused =),  will you masters please help me through this problem?,

some of this is adapted from

[Finding the outward flux through a sphere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113363/finding-the-outward-flux-through-a-sphere)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a systematic answer (which would spoil your fun), but a collection of general and specific hints.

- You are not integrating over a *closed surface*, so Gauss's theorem does not directly apply. (You could conceivably "cap off" your surface usefully, but there's an easier strategy for your situation.)
- In your situation, the flux density $F \cdot n$ is best computed in Cartesian coordinates, not by parametrizing: What is the Cartesian expression for the outward unit normal vector on the unit sphere? What happens when you dot with $F$? (At first you get a polynomial in $x$, $y$, $z$, but because you're on the unit sphere this polynomial simplifies. There must be a mistake in your calculation, probably a sign error; I didn't check carefully.)
- The resulting integral can in fact be computed using geometry and a [theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ArchimedesHat-BoxTheorem.html) of Archimedes.
- If you prefer to calculate the integral by integrating, however, you're perfectly correct that the condition $z \geq 1/\sqrt{2}$ gives a restriction on $\phi$. To find the limits on $\phi$, recall that $z = \cos\phi$ on the unit sphere.

Comment: Hmm,  I still seem to miss something -.-,  
http://prntscr.com/b9ux2w

Comment: Hmm,  I still seem to miss something -.-,  
http://prntscr.com/b9ux2w
from here, polar coordinates and a u sub, 
http://prntscr.com/b9uy8d ...  this seems to now work out...,   sooo I tried the triple integrals,  

http://prntscr.com/b9uz5x  depending on the limits here I get different answers..  not sure again :P , 

oook,  trying out the hat box theorem
http://prntscr.com/b9v0e0

...  sooo none of my tries will give similar answers.. , I really have no way of controlling what works and what dont..

I might need some more help :/,  sorry to dissapoint andrew.. (5 min edit limit)

Comment: Just had a closer look at your calculation; there's an extra factor of $\cos\phi$ in the dot product. That aside, the only problem is the limits of $\phi$, which runs from $0$ to $\pi/4$ (where $\cos\phi = 1/\sqrt{2}$).

Comment: really? :D,  well then awesomeness.. I love your approach btw =), thanks for teaching me

Just to be clear, you mean that 

$\int\!\!\!\!\int_S F\cdot n\, dS = \int_0^{\pi/4}\!\!\int_0^{\pi}\sin\phi\cos\phi\,d\theta d\phi$ will solve it?,  I do have issues with those $\phi$ limits  thanks for your time!

Comment: ps, do you have any tips on how to actually check the answer?,  I do use mathematica for the graphics at least =)

Comment: Oh, I was about to give up on this one, for sure.  you are my saviour Andrew! :)

Comment: The double integral in your fourth comment is close: There's an extra factor of $\cos\phi$, and $0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$. The Cartesian calculation sketched in the answer plus the "hat box theorem" says the flux is $2\pi(1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$.

Comment: ok, well translating that to swedish and back again with a runny egg brain;

$\int_0^{\pi/4}\!\!\int_0^{2\pi}\sin\phi\cos^2\phi\,d\theta d\phi$ ,   checking that calculation then , lets hope I get somewhere..  

ps. sorry for not being able to officially upvote you yet, itll show, eventually at least =).

Comment: nope, that seems to be another mistake from my side, hmm, am I interpereting the factor correctly?, probably not,    back to the drawing board
http://prntscr.com/b9wqv9

I really am starting to feel sorry for taking your time. -.-

Comment: Actually, I meant $\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi/4} \sin\phi\, d\phi\, d\theta$. :)

Comment: the chicken has hit the basket, 

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gaNewoyc8fU

thanks a LOT.. I hope that I'll understand where that pesky $cos\phi$ dissapeared to after a good nights sleep full of dreams of math :)  this Swedish chef needs to get his math skills back!, thanks again for sticking with me :)